# Mail::queue not sending email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mail-queue

I'm stuck with sending emails with queues in Laravel 4. Let me describe my problem:

This works:

```
Mail::send('emails.validateEmail', array("username" => Input::get("username"), "code" => $code), function($message){
$message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('username'))
    ->subject('Some subject');
});
```

However this doesn't work:

```
Mail::queue('emails.validateEmail', array("username" => Input::get("username"), "code" => $code), function($message){
    $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('username'))
        ->subject('Some subject');
    });
```

I created `failed_jobs` table where I keep all failed jobs from worker and in that table I found this error:

```
{"job":"mailer@handleQueuedMessage","data":{"view":"emails.validateEmail","data":{"username":"some_username","code":"MMgNSoaFcyGoIy10sIKgkwUOdux3tM"},"callback":"C:38:\"Illuminate\\Support\\SerializableClosure\":155:{a:2:{i:0;s:126:\"function ($message) {\n    $message->to(\\Input::get('email'), \\Input::get('username'))->subject('Some subject');\n};\";i:1;a:0:{}}}"}}
```

Also I found this:
http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=12672

.. I followed all instructions from previous link but I'm keep getting this error message.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

EDIT: emails.validateEmail file

```
Hello {{ $username }}!<br>

<p>some text</p><br>


<a href="{{ URL::route('validate') }}?code={{ $code }}&username={{ $username }}">{{ URL::route("validate") }}?code={{ $code }}&username={{ $username }}</a><br><br>

some more text
```

Comment: Can you post your `emails.validateEmail` view file?

Comment: What queue driver are you using?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I'm using beanstalkd

Comment: Does it happen if you switch to the sync driver?

Comment: Try moving the `->subect('subject');` onto the same line as the `$message->to()` with no break in the gap. That *might* cause a serialization issue.

Comment: Moved it, and I still get failed_job. Just to mention, I'm having multiple mail:queue commands in my app, and all of them works except this one, but they are completely same as this one, they just have different text inside email view.

Comment: Let us <a href="http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59102/discussion-between-the-shift-exchange-and-alen">continue this discussion in chat</a>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your error job - it seems like it is passing in the `Input::get()` commands into the serialization, rather than the data from those commands.

So I think you need to do something like this to make it work:

```
$data['email'] = Input::get('email');
$data['username'] = Input::get('username');
Mail::queue('emails.validateEmail', array("username" => Input::get("username"), "code" => $code), function($message) use ($data){
    $message->to($data['email'], $data['username'])->subject('Some subject');
    });
```